# Group Action Property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

If a group $G$ is acting on another group $N$, $g \in G$ and $m,n \in N$,is it true that $g\cdot(mn)= (g\cdot m)(g\cdot n)$ where $\cdot$ represents the group action and $mn$ represents the product in the group $N$.

> I am trying to verify that the group product in a semidirect product is associative and seems to rely on this fact, but I can't see why that is true from the definition after playing around with it for a little while.

Comment: That is not a part of the definition of a group action.  If you wanted that to happen, it would entirely depend on how your particular action is defined.

Comment: Not in general.  I suspect that would only be true for a few highly restricted actions.

Comment: @Randall Yeah it is obviously not part of the definition nor did it seem to follow from the definition. I guess I need to check my work on the proof of associativity of the semidirect product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very often, groups act on objects with some structure by structure preserving maps.  For example, a group may act on a topological space by homeomorphisms; or on a ring by ring automorphisms; or on another group by group automorphisms.  If a group acts on another group by group automorphisms, that means precisely that $g\cdot (m n) = (g\cdot m) (g\cdot n)$.  Put another way, an action $\alpha$ of $G$ on $N$ by automorphisms is a homomorphism $\alpha: G \to \text{Aut}(N)$.

In the definition of a semi-direct product of groups, the group which acts is required to act by automorphisms on the acted-upon group.  This cannot be derived from something else, it is a requirement. Go back to your text or lecture notes, or the discussion of semi-direct products in some reference work, and you will see that is the case.

Comment: I had just realized I had forgotten about this out on my own (i.e. that I forgot that it is acting by automorphisms by definition of semidirect product), and came back to update my question. You confirmed my thought, thanks !